# Как проигнорировать нажатие ссылки, чтобы сработало только событие OnClick?

Tags: javascript, ссылки, браузер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проигнорировать нажатие ссылки, чтобы сработало только событие `OnClick`?

В Опере и Хроме с этим отлично справляется ссылка такого типа:

```
<a href="/index2.html" OnClick="func(); return false;">ссылка</a>
```

Точнее будет сказать, что это **`"return false;`"** а под **"`func();`"** я подразумеваю свою любую функцию. Только такая конструкция у меня **не** работает в двух браузерах

1. Мазила;
2. IE (Как не странно) - не обязательно но тоже хотелось бы.

Все остальные, нужные мне браузеры кушают нормально.

Comment: Попробуйте оставить только одну вашу функцию, которая возвращала бы false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте в начале вашей функции func();

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Вы тем самым отмените дэфолтное поведение события - в данном случае переход по ссылке.

Comment: Спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 1):

перенести return false в саму функцию, в конец